# Where in Amsterdam can I dispose of unused/malfunctioning electrical appliances?

Tags: netherlands, electrical-goods, amsterdam

I have this microwave which stutters and doesn't always work. I could theoretically go fix it somewhere but I got another one, and I want to get rid of the old one. Still, it's a shame (and environmentally unfriendly) to just set down outside in the rain and snow. It can either be recycled for parts or fixed/refurbished. I don't want any money for it. What's the responsible way to give it away / have it recycled / "donate" it?

Answer (score 3):

From the handy [iAmsterdam site](http://www.iamsterdam.com/en)

> [Amsterdam Centre District refuse collection](http://www.iamsterdam.com/en/local/live/utilities-and-maintenance/refuse/refuse-centre)
>
> Bulky waste
>
> Either take bulky refuse to a waste collection point (in Dutch) or telephone 020 256 3555 to register it for free collection. There is no scheduled bulky waste collection in the Centre. Once you have arranged collection, put items on the pavement on the designated day ensuring the collection services can easily access the refuse. Waste from construction and demolition works needs to be put out for collection in a special ‘Big Bag’, available at your local DIY store. Electronics, electrical goods and furniture can be collected as bulky refuse or taken to a waste collection point.
>
> [M]any goods may be given a new life at your local second-hand store (kringloopwinkel). A list of licensed stores in Noord-Holland is [available here](https://www.kringloop-info.nl/kringloopwinkels-provincie-noord-holland/) (in Dutch). Also keep in mind that if you are purchasing new electrical goods or appliances, shops in the Netherlands can receive and recycle your old product – either at time of purchase or delivery.

Comment: It doesn't actually say whether the kringloopwinkels accept malfunctioning equipment; plus, it might not be practicable for me to carry it all the way there. Do they do pickup?